# Laravel app development on apache but deploying it on nginx server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, nginx, server

We are planning to develop a Laravel 5.4 web application on apache on windows but we will deploy it on nginx server.

The question is, does it have any effect or bugs while deploying due to server environment changes ?

Or we must use nginx as a local server as well ?

Comment: Only if you're reliant on changes you make in .htaccess like rewrite rules or redirects since nginx doesn't have .htaccess.    However, for the most part, Apache and Nginx just pass off* the request to PHP.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would highly suggest looking at [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead). It will allow you to use a much more similar environment to what it sounds like your production environment will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop on apache you need the htaccess in `/public` folder. In nginx this is not needed. The short and simple answer is no, you will not have any issues, but the most complex answer is depends on what kind of app you are develop.